# Running U-boot on a Pi Zero W

Tags: pi-zero-w, u-boot, buildroot

I'm trying to run u-boot on a Pi Zero W, but after powering up, the Pi shows only the rainbow screen.

I used these [instruction](http://www.embeddedforu.com/embedded-linux/raspberry-pi/how-to-compile-mainline-u-boot-for-raspberry-pi/), but with a different config file, `configs/rpi_defconfig`.

I also tried the different methods, but had the same result, the rainbow screen.

May be someone knows the right configuration of U-Boot for the Pi Zero W?
Or maybe the Pi Zero W  isn't supported by U-Boot?

The software version is: buildroot 2017.05 which contains U-boot 2017.03.

**Update 2017-06-30**

I has found out u-boot doesn't support Pi Zero W and u-boot team doesn't have any plans about adding this support. So I decided to fix it and publish u-boot patch to comunity as well.

U-boot supports Pi A+. So if I understand key differences between Pi Zero and Pi A+ (like connection between BCM2835 and SD card, BCM2835 and HDMI and etc.), I will able to do it with less problems.

So right now I have only 2 question:

Is there full schematic of RPi A+ and RPi Zero W?

Or what is the key difference between RPi A+ and RPi Zero W?

**Update 2017-10-19**

I've made a [path](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/841439/) to support the RPi Zero W.
It passed the review, but it was not accepted into master branch. 
To use it, download and apply:

`git apply U-Boot-v2-1-1-add-support-for-Raspberry-Pi-Zero-W.patch`

and after type to configure:

`make rpi_0_w_defconfig`

**Update 2017-11-28**

I fixed  the build  problem, you can download a new patch from link above or this [one](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/841439/)

Comment: Did you succeed? I'm in the same situation.

Comment: yes, see update part of the post

Comment: I tried with the latest u-boot version (2018.03), copied u-boot.bin on the sd-card, renaming it kernel.img.
It's not booting. The green light is flashing 7 times (kernel.img not recognized).
Have you tried with the latest u-boot version?
Which version where you using?

Comment: @Rémi, when I used it at the last time, my version was 2018.01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer to myself question, sorry for that.

My patch was accepted into the u-boot main branch,
and now if you want t on to run u-boot on a Pi Zero W, you can just use u-boot main repository.

Comment: Hi, have you tested this with QEMU?

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no full schematics for RPi A+ or RPi Zero W and there won't be according to the [statement](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/issues/347) of Ben Nuttall (foundation employee):

> Raspberry Pi has never been open hardware. All our software is open source, and we release as much of the hardware schematics as we can.

But there are [device tree sources](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/extra/dt-blob.dts) for the firmware and personally i made a RFC patch series on linux-rpi-kernel.

Important differences regarding to U-Boot:

- both boards have different revisions in the OTP of the BCM2835 (mapping entry for RPI Zero W is currently missing in U-Boot)
- RPi Zero has Bluetooth which is connected to UART0
- RPi Zero has Wifi which is connected to MMC/SDIO interface

Answer (score -1):

I downloaded u-boot from DENX and applied the patch you created, which created the rpi_0_w_defconfig.

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 5.4.0 20160609
```

I created a build script in the /uboot directory:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/gcc-linaro-7.1.1-2017.08-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin
which arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
make distclean
make clean
make mrproper
make -j12 ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- rpi_0_w_defconfig all
```

I applied the patch successfully, however when I build rpi_defconfig I am successful. When I build rpi_0_w_defconfig I receive the following error from make:

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- rpi_0_w_defconfig all
from arch/arm/lib/asm-offsets.c:15:
./arch/arm/include/asm/barriers.h:33:24: error: operator '>=' has no left operand
 #if __LINUX_ARM_ARCH__ >= 7
Kbuild:64: recipe for target 'arch/arm/lib/asm-offsets.s' failed
make[2]: *** [arch/arm/lib/asm-offsets.s] Error 1
Makefile:1332: recipe for target 'prepare0' failed
make[1]: *** [prepare0] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  HOSTLD  scripts/dtc/dtc
Makefile:461: recipe for target '__build_one_by_one' failed
make: *** [__build_one_by_one] Error 2
```

Any suggestions?

**update** 2017-11-12

U-Boot buildroot-2017.08.1 successfully builds with patch applied through git with both board names "rpi" and "rpi0". Once I applied the patch in the source directory *buildroot/* I was also able to successfully build with board name "rpi_0_w".

The patch in the DENX ftp download was placed in *uboot/config/* rather than the source directory *uboot/*. Upon moving to *uboot/* and applying the patch using Git, I received the following errors with regard to the device tree compiler and the device tree binaries:

```
  SYM     u-boot.sym
  DTC     arch/arm/dts/bcm2836-rpi-2-b.dtb
  DTC     arch/arm/dts/bcm2835-rpi-a-plus.dtb
  DTC     arch/arm/dts/bcm2835-rpi-b.dtb
  DTC     arch/arm/dts/bcm2837-rpi-3-b.dtb
  DTC     arch/arm/dts/bcm2835-rpi-b-plus.dtb
  DTC     arch/arm/dts/bcm2835-rpi-b-rev2.dtb
  DTC     arch/arm/dts/bcm2835-rpi-a.dtb
  DTC     arch/arm/dts/bcm2835-rpi-zero-w.dtb
arch/arm/dts/bcm2835-rpi-zero-w.dtb: ERROR (phandle_references): Reference to non-existent node or label "alt3"

ERROR: Input tree has errors, aborting (use -f to force output)
scripts/Makefile.lib:319: recipe for target 'arch/arm/dts/bcm2835-rpi-zero-w.dtb' failed
make[3]: *** [arch/arm/dts/bcm2835-rpi-zero-w.dtb] Error 2
dts/Makefile:32: recipe for target 'arch/arm/dts/bcm2835-rpi-zero-w.dtb' failed
make[2]: *** [arch/arm/dts/bcm2835-rpi-zero-w.dtb] Error 2
Makefile:876: recipe for target 'dts/dt.dtb' failed
make[1]: *** [dts/dt.dtb] Error 2
Makefile:461: recipe for target '__build_one_by_one' failed
make: *** [__build_one_by_one] Error 2
```

Comment: Could you tell me which buildroot version did you use?

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: @Barrett, see updates of my post, the u-boot master branch has git commits which clashed with my patch.

Comment: @dessel patch 3-1-1 in u-boot/ directory from git.denx.de successful.

"<stdin>:5:10: fatal error: bcm283x-rpi-usb-host.dtsi: No such file or directory" from buildroot/ with patch listed in make nconfig -> Bootloader -> U-Boot -> Custom U-Boot Patch, and board name as rpi_0_w.

Comment: @Barrett - you can try to remove line the 
`#include "bcm283x-rpi-usb-host.dtsi`
from file `bcm2835-rpi-zero-w.dts`
Are you sure you updated the u-boot master branch?

Comment: @dessel, both removing the `#include "bcm283x-rpi-usb-host.dtsi"` and modifying it to refer to it's location in the build directory `#include "../../../../linux-headers-4.12.14/arch/arm/boot/dts/bcm283x-rpi-usb-host.dtsi"` produced the same results: arch/arm/dts/bcm2835-rpi-zero-w.dtb: ERROR (phandle_references): Reference to non-existent node or label "uart1_gpio14", which is on line 20 of `bcm2835-rpi-zero-w.dts`, contents: `&usb {
 dr_mode = "host";
};`

Comment: @Barrett - I've just checked the build on clean version of the u boot repository.

I got it here:
`git clone git://git.denx.de/u-boot.git`

And it was not necessary to edit any file, needs jast use my patch to master branch.

I also have different compiler version:
`gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)`
I got it from ubuntu repo `sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi`
Let try to change compiler and use a clear version of the u-boot, I mean clone it into new directory.

Comment: @dessel, that's correct, I have U-boot working from Denx, but within buildroot the patch is not.

Comment: @Barrett - for buildroot you can set the custom version of u-boot in your  buildroot config file.

Comment: @dessel, got it. I had 'Build System' set to legacy, needed to be set on 'KConfig' to enable U-Boot version 2017.11. I added the patch and set the Board Defconfig to rpi_0_w. Should the binary format be u-boot.img and MLO binary image? Also could I email you at your email address listed on ozlabs for future correspondence?

Comment: @Barrett, I see you have a lot of questions, of course u can email me.